# Query regarding AWS IAM Service

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

Started recently understanding AWS IAM Roles, Groups, Roles and Permissions.

I understood that groups will be added with some Permissions and whoever the users got added into that group, will have an access to those specific AWS services provided in that group. Where as Role is used to provide an access from one Service to Other. (Say Lambda wants to have an access for CloudWatch).

**My Query is**: Suppose if Group (say 'dev') have added only 2 Permissions policy (say S3FullAccess, LambdaFullAccess)
and Role created for  Lambda Service (having Permission policy "cloudwatchFullAccess"), then does a user from 'dev' group can able to access 'cloudwatch' service?

**EDIT:**
**Another query**: I didnt understood on How do we map Users/Groups to only specific Roles? orelse does Roles can be accessed by every user/group (assuming Permission policies already added in Groups of those services mentioned in the Roles)? Please clear me this too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The permissions from the role are only allowed by a [principal](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/intro-structure.html#intro-structure-principal) (IAM user/IAM role/AWS Service) that has assumed the role. If your user had the permission to assume that IAM role and did it, then yes they would have those permissions.

However based on the policies they have they cannot assume the role, but Lambda (assuming it has a trust policy in place) can assume the IAM role in question.

This means that Lambda can perform any CloudWatch interactions, which would allow a user within the dev group to add code that interacts with CloudWatch within the Lambda function and then when triggering the Lambda function see the output of it.

They would not however be able to see the CloudWatch interface within the console, or directly interact with it on the AWS CLI.

To explain the difference between users, groups and role:

- An IAM user is an entity with which you can interact directly through the console or CLI. It requires credentials to perform these interactions and gains its permissions from policies. It is generally advised not to use these for applications that reside in AWS.
- An IAM group is an entity to group similar IAM users, providing them the same permissions. This allows a hierarchy to be easily maintained. No entity can become a group, it is an assignment to an IAM user.
- An IAM role is similar to a user, in that it can interact with the console or CLI. However, to do this it **must** be assumed, which will provide the entity that assumed it with temporary credentials. An AWS service that assumes the role manages these temporary credentials for you.

For a user to assume the role, 2 things would need to be in place. The role would need to have a trust policy that enables the principal of the IAM user (or account) to assume that role. In addition the user would need to have permission to perform the `sts:AssumeRole` action on the IAM role resource.

More information about this can be found in the [Granting a User Permissions to Switch Roles](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_use_permissions-to-switch.html)
 documentation.

Comment: So, you mean Lambda service can perform CloudWatch interactions, but a user cannot able to have an access for Cloudwatch service, as "Cloudwatch" permission policy not added inside 'dev' Group..? and BTW, I just edited my query, can you pls answer that too..

Comment: Yes, they would not have these permissions directly. The role is assigned to the Lambda which gains these permissions. I have added additional details to answer.

Comment: Regarding Mapping User to Role: May be what you said is correct, but I could not able to follow it, as I have only basic knowledge on IAM. Is there any screenshot possible to have a look at mapping User to Specific Role? BTW, does all Created roles, can be accessed by any Users by default?

Comment: So effectively if a user wants to become a role they have to assume it, this means calling the STS service which will return you a set of temporary credentials. The user then uses those credentials to interact with AWS. It comes down to both the IAM roles trust policy, and the IAM users permissions. A user doesn't normally assume a role unless they're performing an action such as needing to access resources in another account or accessing permissions temporarily that they don't normally have access to.

Comment: The best way is to go through the https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_use_permissions-to-switch.html document to understand.

Comment: No problem, let me know if you have further questions and I'll try to explain. It can definitely become confusing for a beginner :)